# Problemas con formato de Fecha - Confunde días con meses

Tags: php

Tengo un error simple, pero no puedo corregirlo.
Estoy recibiendo un dato tipo object, una fecha y hora, la cual casteo a string

```
INPUT:    (object) 05/11/2020 13:12:52
$ofecha = (string) $xmldata->IDENTIFICACION->TMSTRECEPCION; //Este es el objeto
OUTPUT:   (string) 05/11/2020 13:12:52
```

Luego, esa fecha en string, la intento convertir con formato "d-m-Y", el cual creo que es así.

```
$fecha = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($ofecha));
OUTPUT: (string) 11-05-2020
```

Pero como pueden ver, a pesar de que le doy formato de dia-mes-año, me los esta confundiendo y transformando a otra cosa. Dando vuelta lo que es dia y mes, y arrojandome errores si el mes, que era dia, supera el numero 12:

```
INPUT: 17/11/2020
OUTPUT: 0000-00-00
```

Realice un var_dump() de lo que obtengo para dar más información.

```
$ofecha = $xmldata->IDENTIFICACION->TMSTRECEPCION;
echo var_dump($ofecha)."</br>";
OUTPUT: object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(19) "05/11/2020 13:12:52" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque ya te proponen una solución, me gustaría comentar lo siguiente:

- Efectivamente usaremos el método [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- El primer argumento de dicho método indica el formato en el que se compone la fecha: **`d/m/Y G:i:s`**

  - Aqui recomiendo leas a detalle la tabla de [parámetros](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters)
  - Es necesario que si tu variable incluye fecha y tiempo entonces el formato declarado también lo considere ya que en caso contrario obtendrías este error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in [...]

- El segundo argumento es la marca de tiempo completa (*incluyendo el tiempo*)
- Finalmente damos la salida formateada con [el método `format`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php)

Código:

```
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y G:i:s", "05/11/2020 13:12:52");

$fecha1 = $fecha->format("d-m-Y");

echo $fecha1;
```

Con esta salida:

> 05-11-2020

Comment: Tal y como dices @BetaM, hay que incluir todo dentro de los parámetros.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar con lo siguiente

```php
<?php
    // Le indicas el formato en que viene la fecha
    $fechaAFormatear = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y G:i:s', $ofecha);
    // Le indicas el formato en que quieres mostrar la fecha
    $fecha = $fechaAFormatear->format('Y-m-d');  
?>
```

Espero te solucione tu inconveniente.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool` - Añadi un var_dump() del objeto para dar más contexto, pero tu solución ahora mismo me da ese error.

Comment: @Excorpion Listo, el formato que recibe no estaba completo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) recibe una fecha/hora textual en `Ingles` para que lo transforme en una fecha `Unix`, por eso te da el formato `11-05-2020`. Para obtener lo que quieres puedes usar:

```
$date = date_create('05/11/2020 13:12:52');
return date_format($date, 'm-d-Y');
```

Comment: Con esta solución, el error persiste. Aún confunde dias con meses.